# Using tclap-Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library in Visual Studio2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Is tclap-Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library installable on windows? I want to use this library in my code in Visual Studio2010. I did following steps:
1. add the "..\include" in Property->C/C++->General-> Additional Include Directories 
2. copy include folder in my project folder. 
3. add #include  in my main file. 
But I have following error during compile
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tclap/CmdLine.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an absolute path in the "Additional Include Directories" setting, and make sure that it applies to your configuration as well.  Don't go around copying folders in projects all willy and/or nilly, that just makes life harder.  If the tclap directory is correctly added to your system include path, then #include  will work; if that doesn't work, your system include path is not set correctly.

In more recent versions of VC, you will want to make sure that these settings are set in the appropriate properties files in the Properties explorer.

Comment: I copied "tclap-1.2.1" folder in drive C then put "C:\tclap-1.2.1" in Property->C/C++->General-> Additional Include Directories. But still have same issue.

Comment: Yes. Now it works I set Property->C/C++->General-> Additional Include Directories=C:\tclap-1.2.1\include;.

Comment: Please do not use absolute paths in your projects. It's such a pain when you want to port that project to another machine...

Comment: YOu are absolutely correct; I should have been more clear with respect to the fact that the absolute path should be specified at a system level, not at a project level.  Absolute paths in projects are evil (I keep getting another user's "Desktop" directory in one of my projects...)